# A harmonic function on a domain $D$ is infinitely differentiable on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have the following exercise

> Let $u(x,y)$ be a harmonic function on a domain $D$. Prove that u is infinitely differentiable.

Note: In the context of this question, a domain means an open set that is path-connected.

My question is whether the claim in the exercise is true without further requiring that $D$ should be simply connected.

If I knew that $D$ is simply connected, I could find a conjugate harmonic function $v(x,y)$ such that $f=u+iv$ would be holomorphic on $D$ and thus infinitely differentiable and thus $u$ would be infinitely differentiable. But I'm not sure if this claim is still true without requiring that $D$ is simply connected.

Comment: Being differentiable is a local property, i.e. if a function is differentiable it means it is differentiable at each point. In your case, since D is open, you take a point $x\in D$ and there is a disk with center at $x$. Then you prove that $f$ is differentiable in this disk.

Comment: I don’t think the connectedness is relevant here. Being harmonic and being infinitely differentiable are local properties. Being harmonic in a general domain means being harmonic in each connected component.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. That answers my question. If you want to post an answer, I will accept that as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

$\log|z|$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ but there doesn't exist any analytic function whose real or imaginary part is $\log|z|$. Therefore, simple connectedness is required.

Comment: This does not answer entirely the question: this shows that OP cannot find a holomorphic function $f$ with $\mathrm{Re}(f) = u$.